# setting default value while creating table in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I am working on `SQLite`. I want to create a table namely `user_role` with two column `role_id` and `role_name`. And there is an another table namely `default` that contain `role_name` and `default_val`.

I want to set Default value of `role_id` in the time of creating the table `user_role` and the Default value have to be retrieved from the table `default`.

I am new to SQLite and have to idea about the way to doing such recursive query. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#dfltval) says:

> An explicit DEFAULT clause may specify that the default value is NULL, a string constant, a blob constant, a signed-number, or any constant expression enclosed in parentheses.

You would need to use a subquery, which is not allowed.

However, you could use a [trigger](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) that sets the ID if none was specified:

```
CREATE TRIGGER user_role_id_default
AFTER INSERT ON user_role
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN NEW.role_id IS NULL
BEGIN
    UPDATE user_role
    SET role_id = (SELECT default_val
                   FROM "default"
                   WHERE role_name = NEW.role_name)
    WHERE rowid = NEW.rowid;
END;
```

Comment: That's perfect. Thank you. :)